# why can't I see Razor item for webforms in visual studio 2010

Tags: asp.net

It is said here [Can we use Razor on an existing ASP.NET 4 website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3253869/can-we-use-razor-on-an-existing-asp-net-4-website) that I should see it even in webform project if MVC3 is installed but I can't. Why?

Isn't Razor installed with MVC3?

Comment: Razor needs to be installed too.

Comment: Have you added the Razor page? in .aspx page Inellisense will not work.

From answer you refer: **You don't need to create a new Web Pages site (as per the instructions). You can just open up an existing web site, right click the site's root folder, click add item and you should see "Web Page (Razor)" as an option.**

Comment: Yes it's installed since I said Mvc3 is no?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Visual Studio provides support only for ASP.NET Websites (using .NET 4.0 of course) and not for ASP.NET applications. This being said there is nothing preventing you from adding manually a `.cshtml` page to an existing ASP.NET application and it will work. It's just that you don't get the Visual Studio Wizard support but who cares about it anyway?

Comment: Not too strange. It's clearly something Microsoft thinks is for the "children", not the "adults".