# Razor for .cshtml files in .Net ClassLibrary

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

i need to use razor in my dll, so i added nuget packet MVC , create folder view with Web.Configue inside ,cleare and rebuild solutions and nothing. Any suggestions what I'm missing ?
**Class Library project**

[image]

**References in project**

[image]

**Web.config**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="MyDllRootNameSpace" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: What NuGet have you added?

Comment: I suspect you are looking for `RazorEngine` package rather than MVC packages.

Comment: MVC ,webApiClient,Razor  packages are installed in project

Comment: If this is client library, then you don't need any MVC packages - all you need is `RazorEngine` package

Comment: Microsoft.AspNet.Razor package is installed  or you are talking about some other package?

Comment: I'm talking about this project: https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine

Comment: it's not a solution I need to make it work at the same way as in relativ MVC and API projects

Comment: In that case you need to make your project a Web project. There is no other way.

Comment: U can of course use RazorEngine outside MVC (it works pretty nice for example mail templates rendering) but rember that it has some limitations like u cannot use so usefull html helpers.

Comment: What is your use case ? Do you want to write a module of your application inside a DLL and use it in a webproject ? Or is there some other usecase ?

Answer (score 5):

You need to install RazorEngine.

RazorEngine is what gives MVC the ability to write C# code in .cshtml files.

Use this for reference:

[Make your own view engine](http://buildstarted.com/2010/11/22/making-your-own-viewengine-with-markdown/)

[Installing razor engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251396/installing-the-razor-view-engine-for-visual-studio)

[Install razor engine outside of mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808348/using-razor-without-mvc)